# When MATLAB mode is installed opening an m file gives a file mode specification error

Tags: matlab, octave

I have installed the `matlab-mode-20160902.459` package from MELPA and whenever I open an m file (i.e., a file with the file extension `.m` which is the file extension of most MATLAB/GNU Octave scripts) I get an error message shown in the below screenshot:

[image]

[Here](https://github.com/fusion809/emacs/blob/050433d763a7676da60b549507b7779ed5f5114e/.emacs) is my present `~/.emacs` file. As you can see on [line 129](https://github.com/fusion809/emacs/blob/050433d763a7676da60b549507b7779ed5f5114e/.emacs#L129) I have added the line:

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.m$" . matlab-mode))
```

to hopefully autoload `matlab-mode` whenever I open an m file. I really have no idea how to fix this error as I haven't pressed C-x when I opened this file... If relevant I opened my m files using the Emacs directory browser shown in the screenshot.

Is it perhaps that this `~/.emacs` line that sets `.m` files to be handled by `matlab-mode` conflicts with the default handling of `.m` files as Objective C files? Regardless of the cause a solution would be wonderful. I don't ever code in objective C (I am a loyal Linux user with no interest in iOS or macOS development), but I do code in GNU Octave / MATLAB, so setting m files as being associated with `matlab-mode` would be ideal.

**EDIT**:

I have tried using `octave-mod` instead by adding:

```
(setq auto-mode-alist
      (cons '("\\.m$" . octave-mode) auto-mode-alist))
(add-hook 'octave-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (abbrev-mode 1)
            (auto-fill-mode 1)
            (if (eq window-system 'x)
                (font-lock-mode 1))))
```

to my `~/.emacs` file (in accordance with [this guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.0/Using-Octave-Mode.html)). That gave the same error when opening an `~/.emacs` file (and yes I did remove the `matlab-mode` line before I added these lines to make it a fair test of whether it works).

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14941995/emacs-change-file-extension-mode-association) at StackOverflow but neither upvoted answer (which presently are [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16711771/1876983) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14951267/1876983)) worked for me: they both returned the same error whenever I opened an m file and neither caused syntax-highlighting of the m file to occur.

The backtrace generated by going to Options→Enter Debugger on Error was, when I opened the m file `/home/fusion809/GitHub/mine/scripts/GNU_Octave/first.m`:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-error "Cannot open load file" "No such file or directory" "octave-mode")
  octave-mode()
  set-auto-mode-0(octave-mode nil)
  set-auto-mode()
  normal-mode(t)
  after-find-file(nil t)
  find-file-noselect-1(#<buffer first.m> "~/GitHub/mine/scripts/GNU_Octave/first.m" nil nil "~/GitHub/mine/scripts/GNU_Octave/first.m" (21370145 2052))
  find-file-noselect("/home/fusion809/GitHub/mine/scripts/GNU_Octave/first.m" nil nil nil)
  find-file-other-window("/home/fusion809/GitHub/mine/scripts/GNU_Octave/first.m")
  dired-mouse-find-file-other-window((mouse-2 (#<window 3 on GNU_Octave> 419 (546 . 123) 39532480 nil 419 (60 . 6) nil (6 . 15) (9 . 18))))
  funcall-interactively(dired-mouse-find-file-other-window (mouse-2 (#<window 3 on GNU_Octave> 419 (546 . 123) 39532480 nil 419 (60 . 6) nil (6 . 15) (9 . 18))))
  call-interactively(dired-mouse-find-file-other-window nil nil)
  command-execute(dired-mouse-find-file-other-window)
```

With MATLAB mode (instead of Octave mode as in the last backtrace) I get the backtrace http://paste2.org/wDE8VcbV (too long to paste here).

Comment: Please, activate `Options->Enter Debugger On Error` and paste the backtrace here when you get it on the file mode specification error.

Comment: Done, refer to the last paragraph of the question. I thought `octave-mode` came pre-installed with Emacs. I have Emacs 25.1.90 (the latest experimental release). I searched ELPA for the package `octave-mode` but I couldn't find it...

Comment: That's an easy one. You do not have `octave-mode` installed. Install it if you want to use it.

Comment: Didn't you read my last comment? I don't know how to install it so it isn't so easy. I've searched MELPA for it. I've also got other package archives enabled (see https://github.com/fusion809/emacs/blob/master/.emacs for details) and still I can't find it in the package list generated by `M-x package-list`.

Comment: Should be in `lisp/progmodes` that comes with emacs. Hm.

Comment: I've also added what happens with MATLAB mode (which I do have installed) instead of Octave mode.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49851/discussion-between-tobias-and-brenton-horne).

Comment: Is there any reason why you're using the `--devel` version of emacs? Though the devel or master build of emacs are stable enough, it's better for beginners to stick to stable version. 
I do not see it bringing any major benefits for a beginner

Comment: Call it a weird obsession if you would. I have the stable version also installed and I sometimes use it too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This part](https://github.com/fusion809/emacs/blob/050433d763a7676da60b549507b7779ed5f5114e/.emacs#L104) of your config is causing the problem. You should use something like `cua-mode` instead of binding keys like <kbd>C-c</kbd> and <kbd>C-x</kbd>, which conflict with commonly used prefixes in emacs. `cua-mode` should make some of key combinations you use work as expected, and give you a way to use proper keybindings that begin with <kbd>C-c</kbd> and <kbd>C-x</kbd>.

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/CUA-Bindings.html

Comment: Wrong question. This question isn't about my keybindings it's about MATLAB/Octave mode!

Comment: @BrentonHorne Note, that DoMiNeLa10 is right. You can try to comment out the lines `(global-set-key (kbd "C-c") 'kill-ring-save)` and `(global-set-key (kbd "C-x") 'kill-region)` in your config and restart emacs. You will see that the file mode specification error goes away.

Comment: I'll be ****ed, it worked for MATLAB. But not Octave. Octave is giving: `File error: Cannot open load file, No such file or directory, octave-mode`. This question is about MATLAB, should I accept his answer and create a new question specific to Octave mode?

Comment: @BrentonHorne This is not so much about `octave-mode` but more about something wired going on with your installation or your setup of `load-path`. I've invited you to a discussion at http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49851/discussion-between-tobias-and-brenton-horne. Please, join now. I do not have too much time.